# SSR - using loaders waiting for product info to get fetched

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I recently started learning Next.js, and now building an e-commerce using it
I got baffled whether I should to implement a placeholder for the product's info in product page (getServerSideProps used) or it's irrational since the page is going to be delivered to the browser after getServersideProps injects the data into the component.

any help or articles suggestions would be appreciated.

Try to figure out some features of next.js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.